# How to update PHPUnit on Codeship

Tags: phpunit, codeship

PHPUnit version is PHPUnit 4.3.5 on Codeship. But PHPUnit 5.2 is the current stable release series.

How can I use PHPUnit 5.2.5 on Codeship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this before `composer install` in *"Setup Commands"* section:

```
composer global remove "phpunit/phpunit" --update-with-dependencies
composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=5.*"
```

It works for me!